# GridLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I created a `GridLayout` and `CardView`, but card view not working I am using Android Studio 3.0.1

When I look in the Design View, everything looks right. But when I look up the run, I do not see the card on it. Showing text and background only on that. Please help me
I am facing troubles with the layout when i launch it on device with android version 5.1 `Lolipop`. please assist, it does not display a the cards views

android version 5.1 Lolipop

[image: image1]

Design View

[image: iamge2]

Build Gradle

[image: iamge3]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backpic"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="myapplication.cardview.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:text="Card View"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>



    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="14dp">

        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/pi"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Card"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/pi"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Card"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/pi"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Card"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/pi"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Card"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 3 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/pi"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Card"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/pi"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Card"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer! It is now working on Lollipop as well (API 21) Tested & working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @sunil-kumar if my answer solved your problem, please accept it. And, if not let me know what went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with Lollipop devices although Oreo devices worked fine.
We have to use support library instead of default one.

Here is the fix:

in build.gradle

```
androidx
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
or
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28+'

 <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:columnCount="3"
                    app:rowCount="3">

                <ImageView                            
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tools"/>

  ...

 </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your project as shown below:

**Build Gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.careerdost"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

**XML Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="yourPackageName.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Title Headline"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test3"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test4"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Styles**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarLogo</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="logo">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

**Java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

[image: Tested on Emulator - API 22]

Success! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your text is showing below because you are using Linear layout instead of FrameLayout and view is working fine. if your image is hiding Cardview then you can use cardusecompatpadding as true in XML. In future try to avoid Cardview make as the main Layout use another layout as the main layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Card View"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/chatbg" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Card"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/chatbg" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Card"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/chatbg" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Card"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </ FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/chatbg" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Card"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/chatbg" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Card"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/chatbg" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Card"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` instead of 
the default `GridLayout`.
Check the answer in the comments under the tutorial video here: [Android Studio Tutorial - Grid Layout and CardView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUPM387qyrw)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` instead of the default `GridLayout` and replace the errors in the xml by replacing android: to app: also add     `implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'` to your dependency